# XNA - Missing Namespace for Video and VideoPlayer?

Tags: c#, namespaces, xna

Today I tried to include some videos for cutscenes but I failed on even getting the variables recognized.

If I try to access Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Video or Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.VideoPlayer it is just missing.
.Media exists but Video/VideoPlayer is just not there
I also can't use "using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;".

If I copy the exact same project to the example project on the Microsoft website it recognizes "Video" and "VideoPlayer" but of course everything else will not work cause of the wrong namespace, missing content and all that stuff.

I already reinstalled the complete SDK with XNA and .NET Frameworks but it still doesn't work.

If I create a new project and copy it there it doesn't work too, did I miss something?
Do I need something else except using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Video?
I compared the full projects but couldn't find any difference at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video.dll`.

That is where those two classes are located.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project is missing a reference to the assembly: `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll`.

**UPDATE:**
Kendall Frey is right, although Microsoft says in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.videoplayer(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) that the `Video` and `VideoPlayer` classes are in `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll`, this information is incorrect and these classes are really in `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer but this could be helpful..
You can try to install nuget package **directxtk_desktop_2015** this will fix issue.
[here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_desktop_2015/) is reference link.